# Verilog macro definition simulation error

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm getting error in spectre when trying to simulate .v code having macro defined in below fashion -

```
`define ABC `value
```

...

It says `` `value `` is not recognized directive or macro [2.7.3][16.3.1][16(IEEE)]

Comment: How do you think  ```value`` is supposed to be defined?

Comment: you need to define *value* as well: `define value something

Comment: yes value is also to be defined before calling module but even after defining it at top level, it seems value is not being taken by the simulator. When I defined value at the lowest level then simulator and did give any error. Strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `value` is not defined in the *same* file **and** *before* the reference to it, you have problem you are not showing us.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that value has to be defined in a level above this module. Thanks for your answer.